# Raspberry PI enter Display sleep

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

is it possible to get the Rasperry PI into display sleep mode (After pressing the touchscreen reactivate)?

This code is only for disable the display

`sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power'`

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for everyone with the same problem as me, I found a solution:

`sudo XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0.0 xset dpms force on` for turning on

`sudo XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0.0 xset dpms force off` for turning off the display in the ssh remote connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following in the .xinitrc file if you are running X:

```
xset s on
```

To turn of the terminal screen, you could do:

```
setterm -powersave on -blank 1
```

More information on screen blanking on: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-disable-screen-blanking-screen-going-blank.html

Comment: `setterm: cannot (un)set powersave mode` comes this error :(
And is there a way to only activate the sleep mode. (After moving mouse or something else should reactivate)